# Change login button text Facebook SDK 4.7

Tags: facebook-android-sdk

I've successfully upgraded my facebook SDK to v4.7. However, my previous approach to change the login text isn't working anymore. I used

```
fb:login_text="Facebook"
```

attribute in my Facebook's login button previously, and it worked fine. Now, after upgrading to 4.7, it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33176287/how-to-change-text-of-facebook-button-in-facebook-sdk-4-7-0-android) solved my problem.

Answer is...Put these 3 lines in the strings.xml file.

```
<string name="com_facebook_loginview_log_out_button"></string>
    <string name="com_facebook_loginview_log_in_button"></string>
    <string name="com_facebook_loginview_log_in_button_long">Facebook</string>
```