# How to change text of facebook button in Facebook sdk 4.7.0 android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-studio, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am using facebook to login in my app and i want to change default text of facebook login button.how can i do that,

```
   <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
        android:id="@+id/authButton"
        android:text="facebbok"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:paddingBottom="12dp"
        android:paddingTop="12dp" />
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Add to your strings.xml:

```
<string name="com_facebook_loginview_log_out_button">Custom Log out</string>
<string name="com_facebook_loginview_log_in_button">Custom Log</string>
<string name="com_facebook_loginview_log_in_button_long">Custom Log in</string>
```

Answer (score 4):

Use Facebook namespace

```
<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
            android:id="@+id/signup_signupFacebookButton"                           
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"                
            xmlns:facebook="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            facebook:com_facebook_login_text="Sign up with Facebook"                
        </com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton>
```